# Java ResultSet Closed how to fix it

Tags: java, database, sqlite

The problem is when I click on the Update Button to Insert Form to textfield where I can edit Appointments but when I click the UpdateButton there was An error "Result Set Closed"

```
try {
    int row = jTable5.getSelectedRow();
    String Table_Click = (jTable5.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).toString());
    String sql = "Select Ap.Appointment_ID,Ap.Doc_ID,(Ut.First_Name) As Doc_FirstName,Ut.Middle_Name As Doc_MiddleName,Ut.Last_Name As Doc_LastName,Ap.Department_ID,Dt.Department_Name,Ap.Patient_ID,Pr.First_Name,Pr.Middle_Name,Pr.Last_Name,Ap.SchedDate,Ap.Description,Ap.App_Date_Registered from Appointment_Table As Ap\n" +
                     "inner join User_Table As Ut on Ap.Doc_ID=Ut.ID\n" +
                     "inner join Patient_Records As Pr on Ap.Patient_ID=Pr.Patient_ID\n" +
                     "inner join Department_Table As Dt on Ap.Department_ID=Dt.Department_ID\n" +
                     "where Appointment_ID = '"+Table_Click+"'";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next()) {
        String add0 = rs.getString("Appointment_ID");
        AppointmentID.setText(add0);
        String add1 = rs.getString("Department_Name");
        DoctorDep_Update.setSelectedItem(add1);
        String add2 = rs.getString("Doc_FirstName");
        DoctorName_Update3.setText(add2);
        ....
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
} finally {
    try {
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }

}
```

When I put

```
String add2 = rs.getString("Doc_FirstName");
DoctorName_Update3.setText(add2);
```

the error appears I think there is some mistake in my query but I cannot solve it.. when I try to run it on SQlite Browser result show up

Exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed
at org.sqlite.RS.checkOpen(RS.java:57)
at org.sqlite.RS.findColumn(RS.java:103)
at org.sqlite.RS.getString(RS.java:247)
at Portal.ReceptionistPortal.Update_AppointmentsActionPerformed(ReceptionistPortal.java:7912)
at Portal.ReceptionistPortal.access$1900(ReceptionistPortal.java:32)
at Portal.ReceptionistPortal$24.actionPerformed(ReceptionistPortal.java:2256)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

it is saying that the error is on

```
String add2 = rs.getString("Doc_FirstName");
DoctorName_Update3.setText(add2);
```

Comment: where do you get that? it just tells you that you are trying to access the resultset after it's been closed, meaning out of the scope in which you can access it

Comment: I think you have to check how to use a `PreparedStatement`. It requires variable parameters to be represented by a question mark in the SQL code and explicitly setting the value afterwards via `ps.setString(paramNumber, value)`.

Comment: @Stultuske the `ResultSet` appears closed, but it seems to be never created due to the wrong way to set query parameters. I think the answer by funkyjelly is correct.

Comment: Mixing UI and database code in the same class is a bad idea.  You should write an interface-based repository class to interact with the database.  The UI classes should be injected with a reference to the repository and use it to interact with the database.

Comment: Maybe you could also print the stacktrace when you catch the exception to see exactly which statement it is that generates the exception. `} catch(Exception e) {e.printStacktrace(); ...}`

Comment: Suggestion for improvement: Use `try` with resources: `try (pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) { ...` and you can omit the entire `finally` block.

Comment: @deHaar, while that answer is certainly a quality improvement I don't see how it can prevent an exception that must have been thrown after the query was executed. An ill-formed query should have generated another type of exception I believe

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Maybe we (both and all others) should be waiting for the stack trace to be shown. The wrong way to set query parameters will definitely be an issue, but maybe not the one causing the `Exception`. That's why I haven't put it as answer ;-)

Comment: I updated it sir thank you

Comment: @DummyDummy I have seen you haven't given `Dt.Department_Name` an alias in the SQL `String` but you are accessing the value via the alias `Department_Name`. That will not be an issue in the SQLite browser, but the `ResultSet` in Java might get troubled (and maybe closes itself). So either access the column by `String add1 = rs.getString(6);` (it is column 6, isn't it?) or give it an alias in the SQL `String` like `"..., Dt.Department_Name AS Department_Name,..."`

Comment: I set 'Ut.First_Name' "Doctor First Name" And Alias As Doc_FirstName sir and there was an error in the department Name there is no issue sir

Comment: I know the issue occurs **after** the department id, are you sure it isn't the cause of the problem? Just try my suggestions, maybe one of them helps.

Comment: on the Database I have Patient_Records with 'First_Name, Last_Name ,' and in the User_Table Also have First_Name and Last_Name column name so i set an Alias and try to call it in 
"setstring String add2 = rs.getString("Doc_FirstName");
DoctorName_Update3.setText(add2);

but it is not workinig but when I remove it no error showing

Comment: @DummyDummy  try to show some more code, eg the part on which  you initialize the DB connection and **where you also declare exactly the ResultSet rs**

Answer (score 2):

Try setting you sql String as below :

```
String sql = " .... where Appointment_ID = ? "
```

Then use PreparedStatement's setString method to set your parameter :

```
pst.setString(1,Table_Click);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Comment: its not working for me I am trying to call the Doc_FirstName but it is not working can you please look at the query?

Comment: Do you mean that you get without problems the other 2 fields, "Appointment_ID" and "Department_Name" ? Can you use System.out.println on them to see if you get the expected values ?